# Does VS2008 have somewhat C++0x support?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2008

Does VS2008 have somewhat C++0x standard support?

DUPLICATE [Visual Studio support for new C / C++ standards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146381/visual-studio-support-for-new-c-c-standards)

Comment: Isn't this a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/146381/visual-studio-support-for-new-c-c-standards ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No afaik. I believe VS2010 will have more support:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=922B4655-93D0-4476-BDA4-94CF5F8D4814&displaylang=en

http://blogs.msdn.com/vcblog/archive/2008/10/28/lambdas-auto-and-static-assert-c-0x-features-in-vc10-part-1.aspx