# Is there a c++standard library implementation that includes std::unique_ptr that works with visual-studio 2008?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

In order to add new functionality to an old C++ application I need to include code that uses `std::unique_ptr`. The application is built with VS2008 and the included version of the c++-standard library does not include `std::unique_ptr`.

Is there a version of c++-standard library that compiles on VS2008 and does include `std::unique_ptr`?

Alternatively, is there a way to replicate its functionality?

Comment: Use an up to date compiler, that supports the c++11 standard.

Comment: You can't - unique_ptr is not implementable in older versions of C++.

Comment: Upgrade to MSVS 2015 update 3 at least.

Comment: Use `boost::unique_ptr`.  The boost library has many facilities that become available to VS 2008 that exist for C++ 11 and above.  Not everything mind you, but for unique_ptr, it is there.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Nitpick: To be precise, it's not **fully** implementable with pre c++11 standards, because of lacking the `std::move()` feature. No?

Comment: Unfortunately, updating the compiler is not an option. I started to convert the application to 2015. However, that required newer versions of several of the support libraries. One, wxWidgets, is no longer compatible with the original code and I found that I was having to make extensive changes that risk the stability of the product.

Answer (score 0):

> In order to add new functionality to an old C++ application I need to include code that uses `std::unique_ptr`.

You cannot do that directly. Your only option is to *backport* that code. I'll mention your options to do that below.

> Is there a version of STL that compiles on VS2008 and does include `std::unique_ptr`?

Not that I'm aware of one (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278870/does-vs2008-have-somewhat-c0x-support) as well please). Also I suppose you mean the c++-standard library and not the STL (which is a pre-standard c++ implementation that was provided back in the 90ies of the last century).

> Alternatively, is there a way to replicate its functionality?

There are two (reasonable) options for creating a backport of code using `std::unique_ptr`:

1. A similar functionality is provided with the old standards [`std::auto_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/auto_ptr), but it has some deficiencies compared to `std::uniqe_ptr`.
2. You may try [`boost::unique_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost/movelib/unique_ptr.html) which was a pre c++11 standard implementation.
   This implementation fixes a number of the flaws provided with the `std::auto_ptr`, but lacks real moving still (with older boost versions that are VS2008 compatible).

Comment: May the @downvoter please explain what's wrong with this question or answer here?