# Solve this Error ,while using 'export' keyword in templates?

Tags: c++, templates, export

Program :main.cpp

```
 struct X {
            int x;
           };

export template <class T> T const& min(T const&, T const&);

int main() 
 {
  return min(2, 3);
 }
```

x.cpp

```
 struct X {
    int  x; 
     };

 export template <class T> T const& min(T const &a, T const &b) {
 return a<b ? a : b;
  }
```

error:Compiling with gcc

```
 export.cpp:23: warning: keyword ‘export’ not implemented, and will be ignored
 export.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
 export.cpp:27: error: call of overloaded ‘min(int, int)’ is ambiguous

 swap.cpp:16: warning: keyword ‘export’ not implemented, and will be ignored
```

error: Compiling with EDG compiler

```
export.cpp", line 27: error: more than one instance of overloaded function    
export.cpp", line 23: error: support for exported templates is disabled
swap.cpp", line 16: error: support for exported templates is disabled
```

Can anyone solve this problem?

Any one explain the usage of export keyword?

Comment: Iam working with EDG compiler also .Can say how to use in EDG

Comment: Yes - don't - there is no point in doing so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your compiler doesn't support separate template compilation. It is a common practice not use separate compilation with templates and distribute templates in header files. Besides that, I spotted several issues.

1. Remove **export** keyword from the declaration. This should take care of *call of overloaded ‘min(int, int)’ is ambiguous* error message. A template may be defined as exported only once in a program.
2. **X** is defined twice. Why?

P.S. I've never seen any code which uses exported templates. A while ago, when I was learning C++, every compiler I tried did not support exported templates. No wonder it's going to be deprecated from C++.

Answer (score 7):

The export keyword is pretty useless and as far as I'm aware EDG is the only compiler to implement it. The keyword is deprecated in C++0x. So as to its usage - don't even consider it.

Comment: +1, EDG is the only compiler to support it and they pushed to remove it from the next standard. It is more of a problem than a solution.

Comment: The export keyword isn't deprecated in C++0x; it's reserved for future use. Its previous meaning hasn't been deprecated; it's been flat out removed - an unusual single stage removal for a standard. </extreme_pedantry>

Comment: @Charles I feel an SO CW question coming on "Suggest new uses for the export keyword" :-)

Answer (score 0):

The `export` keyword has already been [discussed here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279404/what-is-the-best-explantion-for-the-export-keyword-in-the-c-standard).