# Lambda expressions support in VS2008 SP1

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, lambda, c++11

Is there support for lambda expressions from C++ 0x in Visual Studio 2008 SP1? Example below throws me syntax errors. Is there any '-Cpp0x' flag for compiler or something?

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
  vector<int> v;

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) 
  {
    v.push_back(i);
  }

  for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [](int n) { cout << n << " "; });
  cout << endl;
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Stackoverflow question #146381](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146381/visual-studio-support-for-new-c-c-standards)

Simply put: no. Visual Studio 2010 will support C++0x to some extent, but I'm unsure if that will include lambda expressions.

Comment: It will.  In the CTP version anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can... kind of.

The Visual C++ 2008 *compiler* doesn't support lambdas, but you **can** certainly use the Visual C++ 2010 *compilers* from Visual Studio 2008!!

Just install Visual C++ 2010 Express, and then open Visual Studio 2008 and go to:

> Tools`->`Options`->`Project and Solutions`->`VC++ Directories

and then add the following entries:

- For the Win32 platform, insert `$(ProgramFiles)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin` at the **beginning**, and `$(ProgramFiles)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE` at the **end**.
- For the x64 platform, insert `$(ProgramFiles)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\amd64` at the **beginning**.

Now you can use all the VC++ 2010 features from Visual Studio 2008! :)

Answer (score 0):

Visual studio doesnot support, instead use Boost library.