# Win32 Console Project issue

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, hex, syntax-error

I created a Win32 Console project (disabled "precompiled header" option) with my VS2010.

Then I filled the code as below

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void) {
    double d = 0x0.3p10;
    printf ("%.f\n", d);
    return 0;
}
```

The compiler shows a syntax error on the line of `double d = 0x0.3p10;`.

```
: error C2059: syntax error : 'bad suffix on number'
: error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'constant'
: error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'p10'
: error C2065: 'p10' : undeclared identifier
```

Is there something wrong on my project configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Microsoft Visual C++ doesn't support ISO C99. Sorry. There is no workaround except to use a different compiler. See [this question's accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146381/visual-studio-support-for-new-c-c-standards).

Alternatives:

1. [Clang](http://clang.llvm.net) which will work with the MSVC headers. I don't think there are binaries available for it yet though so unless you like compiling compilers...
2. [mingw](http://www.mingw.org) which comes with msys and a complete set of headers of its own for the w32api.
3. [Intel's Compiler Suite](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-compilers/). This integrates with Visual Studio but is non-free.

Comment: I am reading a c language book based on C99. Then what C compiler be recommended on winxp os. thank you.

Comment: Put some alternatives into the answer for you. `mingw` is probably the easiest to get going with; it's `gcc` for Windows basically and very good.