# creating an array of structs in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, data-structures

I'm trying to create an array of structs. Is the code below valid? I keep getting an `expected primary-expression before '{'` token error.

```
int main() {
  int pause;
  struct Customer {
    int uid;
    string name;
  };

  Customer customerRecords[2];
  customerRecords[0] = {25, "Bob Jones"};
  customerRecords[1] = {26, "Jim Smith"};
  cin >> pause;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your example compiles without errors on ideone (gcc-4.5.1) http://www.ideone.com/c9kMr

Comment: This is because of new features inherent to initialization lists and C++0x ... his code does not compile under C++03.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Try this:

```
Customer customerRecords[2] = {{25, "Bob Jones"},
                               {26, "Jim Smith"}};
```

Answer (score 35):

You can't use an initialization-list for a `struct` after it's been initialized.  You've already default-initialized the two `Customer` structs when you declared the array `customerRecords`.  Therefore you're going to have either use member-access syntax to set the value of the non-static data members, initialize the structs using a list of initialization lists when you declare the array itself, or you can create a constructor for your struct and use the default `operator=` member function to initialize the array members.

So either of the following could work:

```
Customer customerRecords[2];
customerRecords[0].uid = 25;
customerRecords[0].name = "Bob Jones";
customerRecords[1].uid = 25;
customerRecords[1].namem = "Jim Smith";
```

Or if you defined a constructor for your struct like:

```
Customer::Customer(int id, string input_name): uid(id), name(input_name) {}
```

You could then do:

```
Customer customerRecords[2];
customerRecords[0] = Customer(25, "Bob Jones");
customerRecords[1] = Customer(26, "Jim Smith");
```

Or you could do the sequence of initialization lists that Tuomas used in his answer.  The reason his initialization-list syntax works is because you're actually initializing the `Customer` structs at the time of the declaration of the array, rather than allowing the structs to be default-initialized which takes place whenever you declare an aggregate data-structure like an array.

Answer (score 9):

Some compilers support compound literals as an extention, allowing this construct:

```
Customer customerRecords[2];
customerRecords[0] = (Customer){25, "Bob Jones"};
customerRecords[1] = (Customer){26, "Jim Smith"};
```

But it's rather unportable.

Comment: It's in C99, so hardly "unportable" (depending on whether you want to support antique compilers or not). I prefer it in C to `MakeCustomer(25, "Foo")` which somehow generates worse code with GCC 4.2. I can't remember if it's in C++; I'm pretty sure `(Customer){.uid=25}` is not (though it may be in C++0x).

Comment: @tc.: MSVC [traditionally neglects C99](http://stackoverflow.com/q/146419); is MSVC 2008 an antique?  (2010 is a little better.)

Comment: If after over a decade, they can't be bothered, I'd say so. Then again, I consider most Windows C code "legacy" in terms of style, if nothing else.

Answer (score 9):

It works perfectly. I have gcc compiler C++11 ready.
Try this and you'll see:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int pause;

    struct Customer
    {
           int uid;
           string name;
    };

    Customer customerRecords[2];
    customerRecords[0] = {25, "Bob Jones"};
    customerRecords[1] = {26, "Jim Smith"};
    cout << customerRecords[0].uid << " " << customerRecords[0].name << endl;
    cout << customerRecords[1].uid << " " << customerRecords[1].name << endl;
    cin >> pause;
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use vector.
First Define the Struct.

```
  struct Customer {
    int uid;
    string name;
  };
```

Then,

```
vector<Customer> array_of_customers;
```

By using vector, you will have more freedom and access in the array of structure.

Now if want to add an struct element in the define array. You can use

```
array_of_customer.push_pack(/* struct element here */)
```

Example:

```
Customer customer1;
customer1.uid = 01;
customer1.name = "John Doe";

Customer customer2;
customer2.uid = 02;
customer2.name = "Blah Blah";


array_of_customers.push_back(customer1);
array_of_customers.push_back(customer2);
```

you have now an array of struct.