# How to write a for statement that iterates through two arrays in c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I have completed an assignment, but Xcode is giving me a warning about the syntax of my for loop, and I'm not sure how to change it. I am new to programming. I am taking a course.

The assignment is to create two char arrays. One for month names, the other for total days in each month, then print both arrays combined sequentially (Jan 31 Feb 28 etc).

This is what I came up with:

```
f()
{
    std::string months[] = { "January", "February", "March" };
    std::string days[] = { "31", "28", "31" };

    stringstream ss;

    for (auto i = 0, j = 0; i < 3, j < 3; ++i, ++j)

    {
        ss << months[i] << " " << days[j] << " ";
    }

}
```

The compiler doesn't like the middle part of the for statement, the test to stop. The message I get says "Expression result unused".

I confess I'm mostly mimicking the samples I've seen from class, but we've never done a loop that evaluates two arrays. I tried a range for loop, but I can't get that to work at all.

Comment: If `i` and `j` never diverge, why have two variables? `i < 3, j < 3` is not a valid expression.

Comment: you are meant to have nested loops

Comment: FYI: [Comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator)

Comment: @tadman, It is valid, hence the warning not being an error.

Comment: Just so you know, they are not char arrays but string arrays (but that's good). I would make them static const. I would also reconsider whether days should be string or int, depending how it's used later.

Comment: @chris Technically, it's not required to be an error, diagnostics are implementation-defined. He's just plain wrong in general that it's not a valid expression.

Comment: @remyabel, I'm going to have to refine these statements to just apply to the major implementations until I figure out exactly what they are and aren't allowed to do. Interesting topic, thanks.

Comment: @remyabel Technically a valid expression in terms of syntax, but also completely invalid in terms of capturing the desired logical condition. Argh, phrasing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> stringstream ss;
> ```

Replace with `std::ostringstream ss;`.

> ```
> for (auto i = 0, j = 0; i < 3, j < 3; ++i, ++j)
> {
>     ss << months[i] << " " << days[j] << " ";
> }
> ```

In `i < 3, j < 3`, the comma operator is used. As http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator says:

> In a comma expression `E1, E2`, the expression `E1` is evaluated, its
>   return value is **discarded**, and its side effects are completed before
>   evaluation of the expression `E2` begins [...]. The return type and value
>   category of the comma operator are exactly the return type and the value
>   category of the second operand, `E2`.

In other words, the `i < 3` part is completely ignored (it does not have any side effects, either), and your code is equivalent to `for (auto i = 0, j = 0; j < 3; ++i, ++j)`.

Here is a simpler example to show this behaviour:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    std::cout << (i != 0, i == 0);
}
```

This prints `1`, because only the `i == 0` is considered.

To me, the question is: What exactly do you want to do? Do you want to print both arrays? In that case, you do not need two different index variables at all:

```
for (auto i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
{
    ss << months[i] << " " << days[i] << " ";
}
```

There is still room for improvement, though. For example, you may want to `assert` that both arrays have the same size before iterating them, and you may want to get rid of the magic number `3` in the loop.

Comment: Wow, that's an impressive answer. Thank you so much for explaining it to me. I've seen the same thing before in something else I'd written, but didn't know why it was happening. Now I know.

Comment: Is there a way to do this with a ranged based for loop?

Comment: @TimElhajj: Not any reasonable one, because here you need to iterate *two* different ranges at the same time, and a range-based for loop is used to iterate *one* range.

Comment: @TimElhajj: I'd like to add that this question (iterating two ranges at once) will become moot once you do what's really needed here, namely creating a class that has two members, one for name and one for days, and then create a collection of that class. Something like `class Month { /* ... */ std::string name; int days; }` to be used in `std::vector<Month>`.

Answer (score 6):

Why would you use two indices? Just write a regular loop:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        ss << months[i] << " " << days[i] << " ";
    }
```

Comment: Yes, I see that now. You're absolutely right. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
i < 3, j < 3
```

to this:

```
i < 3 && j < 3
```

Comment: That is very interesting. you're absolutely right that it works, but it's not as clear to me why. I think it's a temporary writable reference?

Answer (score 1):

Use a single index, and use a single array while you're at it:

```
void f()
{
    struct
    {
        std::string month;
        std::string days;
    } calendar[] = {
        { "January",  "31" },
        { "February", "28" },
        { "March",    "31" }
    };

    for(auto i=0; i<ARRAY_SIZE(calendar); ++i)
    {
        ss << calendar[i].month << " " << caledar[i].days << " ";
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks extremely C-ish to me.

Comment: ha, this is the next part of the question, and it was already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6810656/creating-an-array-of-structs-in-c Thank you!

Comment: @abelenky Do I need to include a library to get that ARRAY_SIZE to run? I can use i < sizeof(calendar)/sizeof(calendar[0]). I am just curious about ARRAY_SIZE. Thank you!

Comment: `ARRAY_SIZE` varies depending on platform/compiler.  Or it may be `_countof(calendar)`.   Do some google depending on your particular platform/compiler to find the right answer.