# How to use Winrt API's in c for creating libraries?

Tags: c, windows-8

I have an existing C libraries which uses Win32 API but it is not supported in windows 8 metro store apps.
I tried calling WinRT API but failed so is there any way ican use WinRT apis in C.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7436144/using-winrt-from-c

Comment: i am not creating a COM component i am creating a library

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you're trying to do - for instance are you looking for WinRT equivalents to Win32 API calls?

Comment: I had a library which was built for win32 but some of the API's are not working in store apps.

Comment: i need to migrate them to winRT

Comment: There's no magic way to answer this question. I'd suggest you provide example code of the Win32 API calls you are trying to port to WinRT.

Comment: SHGetSpecialFolderPath This fuc is not working with metro apps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the question although very general seems to be **specifically** about `SHGetSpecialFolderPath()` on `WinRT` I'll address this:

As you found out WinRT (Metro) apps run in a sandboxed environment which only supports a limited subset of the win32 api.

SHGetSpecialFolderPath is officially [deprecated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762181%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on MSDN and its functionality is not available to WinRT applications. The closest equivalent would be the [ApplicationData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/BR241587) class. Unfortunately calling it from `C` is complicated. I would recommend writing a `C++` helper which your library could call into.