# Can I write Windows phone 8 apps/games with C (not C++)?

Tags: c, windows, ubuntu, windows-phone-8

I absolutely love C language, so I want to learn programming Windows phone 8 with it. Does Microsoft support C language (I don't like C++, so please don't include it here)? If not, do you know any mobile platform which supports C. Also please don't include iOS here because I don't have enough money to buy a Mac or iPhone.
Thank a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can program for Maemo (Nokia N900), MeeGo, Tizen OS (Samsung (soon to be released)), QNX (BlackBerry Playbook, BlackBerry 10), Ubuntu Touch etc. in C. For Android there is NDK, though that wouldn't be the default choice unless you are build games and such.
For Windows Phone, C++ is the default native choice, though you can use C which would be a bit wacky.
References:
[Native code for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681687%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)
[Using WinRT from C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7436144/using-winrt-from-c)