# This code compiles in DevC++without problems but Visual Studio 2008 spits these warnings and refuses to compile. Where is my mistake?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2008

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define SIZE 99             

void mean(int b[]);
void median(int b[]);
void mode(int b[]);
void bubbleSort(int b[]);
int findFrequentValue(int b[]);
int findFrequentIndex(int b[]);
void printHistogram(int b[]);
int * fillResponseArray(int response[]);



int main(void) {

srand(time(NULL));

int response[SIZE]={0}; //first fill with 0's
fillResponseArray(response);

mean(response);
median(response);
mode(response);

return 0;


}     


int * fillResponseArray(int response[]){

int i;

for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
    response[i]=rand()%10;

return response;

}

/*finds mean*/

void mean(int b[]) {

int sum=0;
int i;

printf( "********\n"
    "MEAN\n"
    "********\n\n"
    "The mean is the average value of the data\n"
    "items. The mean is equal to the total of\n"
    "all the data items divided by the number\n"
    "of data items.\n" );

for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
    sum+=b[i];

printf ( "\n%d given responses SUM: %d MEAN: %.2f\n", SIZE, sum, (double)sum/SIZE         );
printf("\n");
}

/*finds median*/

void median(int b[]) {

int i;

printf( "********\n"
"MEDIAN\n"
"********\n");

printf("\nUnsorted array\n");

for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++){

    if(i!=0&&i%10==0)
        printf("\n");

    printf("%d ",b[i]);
}



printf("\n");

bubbleSort(b);

printf("Sorted array\n");

for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++){

    if(i!=0&&i%10==0)
        printf("\n");

    printf("%d ",b[i]);
}
printf("\n\nMEDIAN is the %d th element: %d",SIZE/2,b[SIZE/2]);

printf("\n");

}

/*finds mode*/

void mode(int b[]) {

int frequency[10]={0},i;

printf( "\n********\n"
    "MODE\n"
    "********\n");
printf("Mode is the most frequent value.\n");

/* Fill the frequency array with occurrences of indexes*/

for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
    frequency[ b[i] ]++;

/*print frequency array*/

for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    printf("frequency[%d]= %2d\n",i,frequency[ i ]);

/* print result */

printHistogram(frequency);

printf("\n");
printf("\nMode is %d and appeared %d times", findFrequentIndex(frequency),        findFrequentValue(frequency) );


}

/* Returns the index of most frequent one in frequency array*/

int findFrequentIndex(int b[]){         

int mostFrequent=b[0],i;
int rating=0;

for(i=1;i<10;i++){

    if(b[i]>mostFrequent){

        mostFrequent=b[i];         
        rating=i;               //keep index of mostFrequent one!
    }
}

return rating;

}


/* Returns the value of most frequent occurrence in frequency array*/

int findFrequentValue(int b[]){         

int mostFrequent=b[0],i;

for(i=0;i<10;i++){

    if(b[i+1]>mostFrequent)    //Achtung !!!!!
        mostFrequent=b[i+1];
}

return mostFrequent;

}

/*prints the histogram*/

void printHistogram(int b[]){

int i,j;

for(i=0;i<10;i++){

    printf("\nfrequency[%d] ",i);

    for(j=1;j<=b[i];j++){
            printf("*");
    }

}

}

/*Sort function*/

void bubbleSort(int b[]) {    //Passed by reference

int passes=SIZE-1;
int i,j,temp;

for(i=1;i<=passes;i++){

    for(j=0;j<SIZE-1;j++){

        if(b[j]>b[j+1]){

            temp=b[j+1];
            b[j+1]=b[j];
            b[j]=temp;
        }

    }

}
}
```

> 1>c:\users\turan\documents\visual studio
>   2008\projects\project1\search\search\dsa.c(30) : warning C4024:
>   'fillResponseArray' : different types for formal and actual parameter
>   1 1>c:\users\turan\documents\visual studio
>   2008\projects\project1\search\search\dsa.c(32) : error C2065:
>   'response' : undeclared identifier 1>c:\users\turan\documents\visual
>   studio 2008\projects\project1\search\search\dsa.c(32) : warning C4047:
>   'function' : 'int *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'
>   1>c:\users\turan\documents\visual studio
>   2008\projects\project1\search\search\dsa.c(32) : warning C4024: 'mean'
>   : different types for formal and actual parameter 1
>   1>c:\users\turan\documents\visual studio
>   2008\projects\project1\search\search\dsa.c(33) : error C2065:
>   'response' : undeclared identifier 1>c:\users\turan\documents\visual
>   studio 2008\projects\project1\search\search\dsa.c(33) : warning C4047:
>   'function' : 'int *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'
>   1>c:\users\turan\documents\visual studio
>   2008\projects\project1\search\search\dsa.c(33) : warning C4024:
>   'median' : different types for formal and actual parameter 1
>   1>c:\users\turan\documents\visual studio
>   2008\projects\project1\search\search\dsa.c(34) : error C2065:
>   'response' : undeclared identifier 1>c:\users\turan\documents\visual
>   studio 2008\projects\project1\search\search\dsa.c(34) : warning C4047:
>   'function' : 'int *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'
>   1>c:\users\turan\documents\visual studio
>   2008\projects\project1\search\search\dsa.c(34) : warning C4024: 'mode'
>   : different types for formal and actual parameter 1 1>Build log was
>   saved at "file://c:\Users\Turan\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2008\Projects\Project1\Search\Search\Debug\BuildLog.htm" 1>Search - 5
>   error(s), 9 warning(s)
>   ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I tell Visual Studio/Microsoft's C compiler to allow variable declarations after the first statement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7614397/how-can-i-tell-visual-studio-microsofts-c-compiler-to-allow-variable-declaratio)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't declare a variable after any non-declarations:

```
int main(void)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int response[SIZE]={0};  // This can't go here!
    ...
```

in Visual Studio.  You need to declare your variables at the top of the scope:

```
int main(void)
{
    int response[SIZE]={0};
    srand(time(NULL));
    ....
```

It's a feature of modern C that Visual Studio's C compiler doesn't have.

(There may be other problems with your code, but you're going to have to fix that one first!)

Comment: Thanks for this information. Code worked after your suggestion. How can I upgrade Visual Studio's compiler?

Comment: @user1939432 - you can't. You have to wait for Microsoft to become C99 compliant.

Comment: Yeah, be patient. C99 is only 14 years old.