# why the following cannot compile under Visual Studio 2010 C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

```
// A simple program that computes the square root of a number
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  if (argc < 2)
  {
    fprintf(stdout,"Usage: %s number\n",argv[0]);
    return 1;
  }

  double inputValue = atof(argv[1]);
  double outputValue = sqrt(inputValue);
  fprintf(stdout,"The square root of %g is %g\n",
          inputValue, outputValue);
  return 0;
}
```

I received the following errors

Error   1   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'
Error   2   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'   Error   3   error C2065: 'inputValue' : undeclared identifier
Error   4   error C2065: 'outputValue' : undeclared identifier

Comment: Compiles for me.  Me thinks that code is not a 1:1 translation.

Comment: BTW, if `inputValue` is `0` after the call to `atof`, did the user enter `0` or something invalid? (HINT: you can't know)

Comment: Visual C++ automatically selects C or C++ depending on the extension (.c or .cpp). If it's compiling it as C, then here's one of many duplicates that will answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8496853/why-does-this-code-not-compile

Comment: @Mysticial Sounds spot on to me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you name the file .cpp, it should compile and run fine.

If you name the file .c, however, it will fail.

The reason is that you need to declare all variables at the top of a C function; you cannot declare them at point of use.

Comment: Yes, but the reason behind that is that VS only implements C89.  In C99 you can declare variables wherever you like in a function.  Damn you MS for not showing love to us C fanatics...

Comment: I've lost track of what version of VS purports to support which version of C ;)  But clearly, MSVS2010 doesn't fully support C99 ;)

Comment: It's a conspiracy, period. MS probably wants C to die as much as Linux.

Comment: @EdS: Herb Sutter also publicly stated that they will never will support newer versions on [his blog](http://herbsutter.com/2012/05/03/reader-qa-what-about-vc-and-c99/).

Comment: @JesseGood: Yep, I saw that. VS is C89 and will be forever unless MS changes its mind.

Comment: [MSVS2010 should support C95](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sk54f3f5.aspx)  I'm not sure it's *complete* support, and you need to do some "extra stuff": http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Vsexpressvc/thread/d0c999ec-d2f9-4e61-8b53-0b3d6535f18f/