# Why Microsoft Visual Studio cannot find <stdint.h>?

Tags: c++, std, stdint

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Visual Studio support for new C / C++ standards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146381/visual-studio-support-for-new-c-c-standards)

See the text below from [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types):

The C99 standard includes definitions of several new integer types to enhance the portability of programs[2]. The already available basic integer types were deemed insufficient, because their actual sizes are implementation defined and may vary across different systems. The new types are especially useful in embedded environments where hardware supports usually only several types and that support varies from system to system. All new types are defined in inttypes.h header (cinttypes header in C++) and also are available at stdint.h header (cstdint header in C++). The types can be grouped into the following categories:

My visual studio can not find any of this files:

1. `<cstdint>`
2. `<cinttypes>`
3. `<stdint.h>`
4. `<inttypes.h>`

Why?

Comment: As you noted that's C99. I don't believe VS claims C99 support.

Comment: I don't think this is a dup since your question was very specific, and it was not addressed in the cited dup.

Comment: Early Microsoft compilers, like Visual Studio .Net 2003, used `<stddef.h>` rather than `<stdint.h>`. You can follow the locations of types like `uintptr_t` and `ptrdiff_t` at [Standard Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/323b6b3k(v=vs.71).aspx) on MSDN. The page covers VS2003 through VS2015.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**EDIT**

Note that starting from Visual Studio 2013, [C99 library support](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2013/07/19/c99-library-support-in-visual-studio-2013/) has been added to Visual Studio.

The answer below is my old answer before Visual Studio 2013 added support:

---

MSVC has very poor support for the C language, they do not support anything past C90. Herb Sutter has already publicly stated this [in his blog](http://herbsutter.com/2012/05/03/reader-qa-what-about-vc-and-c99/).

`<cstdint>` is supported from [MSVC2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh874765.aspx).

There is a [msinttypes](https://github.com/chemeris/msinttypes) project (exported from the [original repo](http://code.google.com/p/msinttypes/) on Google Code) that fills the absence of stdint.h and inttypes.h in Microsoft Visual Studio.

Boost also provides [boost/cstdint.hpp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/boost/cstdint.hpp) if you do not have it.

Comment: Visual Studio 2013 (12.0) has stdint.h and inttypes.h

Comment: Yes, that was announced in [July 2013](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/07/19/c99-library-support-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx). I posted this answer in October 2012.

Comment: @JesseGood As your answer is the (only and) accepted one *and* search machines point to this question: Do you mind editing the updated information into your old post?