# Failed building wheel for spacy

Tags: python, scipy, pip, python-wheel, spacy

I'm trying to install spacy by running `pip install spacy` for python version **3.6.1** but continuously i'm getting errors like below,how to get rid of this issue? previously i was having cl.exe not found error, after that i added visual studio path in environment variables where cl.exe exists.

```
     Failed building wheel for spacy
  Running setup.py clean for spacy
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for murmurhash ... error
  Complete output from command c:\users\sh00428701\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\SH0042~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-joi6voav\\murmurhash\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\SH0042~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpa6tzdkovpip-wheel- --python-tag cp36:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for murmurhash
  Running setup.py clean for murmurhash
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for cymem ... error
  Complete output from command c:\users\sh00428701\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\SH0042~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-joi6voav\\cymem\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\SH0042~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpz7p6hkiwpip-wheel- --python-tag cp36:

 ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for cymem
  Running setup.py clean for cymem
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for preshed ... error
  Complete output from command c:\users\sh00428701\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\SH0042~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-joi6voav\\preshed\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\SH0042~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpwppgmyp9pip-wheel- --python-tag cp36:

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for preshed
  Running setup.py clean for preshed
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for thinc ... error
 ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for thinc
  Running setup.py clean for thinc
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for ujson ... error
  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for ujson
  Running setup.py clean for ujson
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for cytoolz ... error
  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for cytoolz
  Running setup.py clean for cytoolz
Failed to build spacy murmurhash cymem preshed thinc ujson cytoolz
Installing collected packages: murmurhash, cymem, preshed, wrapt, tqdm, toolz, cytoolz, plac, pyreadline, dill, termcolor, pathlib, thinc, ujson, regex, spacy
  Running setup.py install for murmurhash ... error

   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ic:\users\sh00428701\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\include -IC:\Users\SH0042~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-joi6voav\murmurhash\murmurhash\include -Ic:\users\sh00428701\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\include -Ic:\users\sh00428701\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\include /EHsc /Tpmurmurhash/mrmr.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\murmurhash/mrmr.obj /Ox /EHsc
    mrmr.cpp
    c1xx: fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'murmurhash/mrmr.cpp': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\bin\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\users\sh00428701\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\SH0042~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-joi6voav\\murmurhash\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\SH0042~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-_j1cxej1-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\SH0042~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-joi6voav\murmurhash\
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A couple thoughts:

- Grab the various wheel files you need from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#spacy and install with `pip install x.whl y.whl etc.`
- Upgrade your version of cpp build tools to 2017 and try pip again

Comment: The first option worked for me on Windows 64 bit, python 2.7. Just a note you also need to cytoolz and ujson from : https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Comment: Dude, you just saved my life on this. Thank you so much

Comment: What's the mac alternative?

Comment: What's the Raspbian/Linux alternative?

Answer (score 32):

for me, `pip install --no-cache-dir spacy` worked

Comment: Awesome! I spent hours trying to figure this out. This simple little line has spared me my sanity. Thanks!

Comment: correct solution if install is failing because your /tmp volume is running out of space

Answer (score 17):

I installed these packages, then it works:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev 
sudo apt-get install python3-dev 
sudo apt-get install libevent-dev
```

Comment: What's the Windows equivalent?

Comment: Whats equivalent for yum RHEL

Comment: is this for ubuntu ?

Comment: on Windows you can use Cygwin's installer (just re-run it again if you already have Cygwin) to add these packages

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

```
# Note, use sudo. I'm in a docker image, so i dont need it.

# install dev libs
apt-get install python-dev -y && \
apt-get install python3-dev -y && \
apt-get install libevent-dev -y && \

# install new gcc
apt-get update && \
apt-get install build-essential software-properties-common -y && \
add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test -y && \
apt-get update && \
apt-get install gcc-snapshot -y && \
apt-get update && \
apt-get install gcc-6 g++-6 -y && \
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-6 60 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-6 && \
apt-get install gcc-4.8 g++-4.8 -y && \
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.8 60 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-4.8;
```

see https://gist.github.com/application2000/73fd6f4bf1be6600a2cf9f56315a2d91

Comment: Updated based on feedback.

Answer (score 2):

`conda install -c conda-forge spacy` worked for me. I have windows 10 and `Python 3.5.3 :: Anaconda custom (64-bit)`

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Ubuntu, just do this

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential python-dev git
```

Now install spacy by

```
pip install -U spacy
```

Answer (score 1):

Download and install from the Gihub source. Here is the link: https://github.com/explosion/spaCy

Use these commands:

```
python -m pip install -U pip venv              # update pip & virtualenv
git clone https://github.com/explosion/spaCy   # clone spaCy
cd spaCy                                       # navigate into directory

venv .env                                      # create environment in .env
source .env/bin/activate                       # activate virtual environment
export PYTHONPATH=`pwd`                        # set Python path to spaCy directory
pip install -r requirements.txt                # install all requirements
python setup.py build_ext --inplace            # compile spaCy
```

Feel free to use only last two commands if not using virtual environment. Follow the official Documentation [here](https://spacy.io/usage/#source)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using it with manually installed python3.6 and trying to install in a 3.6 environment then you maybe missing python3.6-dev

```
sudo apt-get install python3.6-dev
```

also maybe

```
sudo apt-get install gcc
```

This is an answer to particular case.

Comment: Based on the question i assume the op uses windows. So this may not help the OP.

Comment: I agree. Answer is for someone like me who comes searching.

Answer (score 1):

yum -y groupinstall development

WORKED FOR ME

Answer (score 1):

Spacy requires 64-bit python.

Uninstall 32-bit. 
Install 64-bit python.

Try spacy installation again.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for an answer for `spacy 2.X` with `Python 3.8` in `Ubuntu`, I had the same problem. I'm using `venv`. As the other answers were not enough, I write the solution which solved my problem.

1. install the required libraries as mentioned in other answers:

```sh
sudo apt-get install python3-dev libevent-dev build-essential gcc g++
pip install setuptools wheel
```

2. Update pip and install cython

```
pip install -U pip
pip install cython
```

I suspect that updating pip to the newest version solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

At first, install those packages and try to install spacy

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3-dev
sudo apt install libpython3-dev
sudo apt install python3-devel
sudo apt-get install libevent-dev
sudo apt update
```