# Installing spacy

Tags: nlp, spacy

I am trying to install spacy. I am using python 2 and I saw a post [Failed building wheel for spacy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43370851/failed-building-wheel-for-spacy) as I am having the same issue.

I ran `pip install --no-cache-dir spacy` but still I am getting

```
error: command 'C:\\Users\\amuly\\mingw\\bin\\gcc.exe' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
thinc 6.10.3 has requirement dill<0.3.0,>=0.2.7, but you'll have dill 0.2.5 which is incompatible.
Command "c:\users\amuly\anaconda2\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\amuly\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-install-aljpyz\\murmurhash\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\amuly\appdata\local\temp\pip-record-ijwq0r\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\amuly\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-aljpyz\murmurhash\
You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 18.0 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

I am sorry but I am new to this and can't find the solution.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi Amy, I was able to install this package with the same command. Can you try check if pip is correctly set up and you can install any other package?

Comment: Hi, Yes I have been installing packages before. But I am not sure if I need to upgrade it. I have not upgrade it. Do you think that is the reason?

Comment: It seems like and windows gcc error I did a quick search and found below link which can help : https://github.com/develersrl/gccwinbinaries. Additionally, I would suggest to reinstall python dermal for an easy solution.

Comment: @Helly Thanks but I have read that Windows GCC are hard to install and manage. Is there any other solution? I am just trying to have dependency parsing work. If there is any other work around, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

First off, this (dependencies) is the worst part of Python by far and everyone struggles with this.

I notice that you are using pip, but the command that is erring shows your python interpreter is anaconda. Can you do `conda install spacy` instead of `pip install spacy`?

If you aren't using conda environments, you should (or pip and virtualenv, but if you are doing scientific python, conda is a bit cleaner). Environments are ways to keep the dependencies for different projects separate. For example, if you want to create an environment with spacy in it, you'd run

```
conda create -n my_env_name spacy
```

Then you'd run

```
source activate my_env_name
```

to "enter" the environment.

You can add packages later (they don't have to be installed at environment creation time). Once you are in your env, you'd enter into the command line `conda install package_name` - but the installation would stay in that environment.