# installing spaCy with pip failed with error "Failed building wheel for blis"

Tags: pip, spacy, powerpc

Tried to install spaCy with pip (version 20.0.2)

but got error like bellow

```
gcc -c /tmp/pip-install-f2b27qwm/blis/blis/_src/kernels/zen/1/bli_amaxv_zen_int.c -o /tmp/tmpu1wg8fg1/bli_amaxv_zen_int.o -O3 -mavx2 -mfma -mfpmath=sse -march=core-avx2 -fPIC -std=c99 -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L -DBLIS_VERSION_STRING="0.5.1" -DBLIS_IS_BUILDING_LIBRARY -Iinclude/linux-x86_64 -I./frame/3/ -I./frame/ind/ukernels/ -I./frame/1m/ -I./frame/1f/ -I./frame/1/ -I./frame/include -I/tmp/pip-install-f2b27qwm/blis/blis/_src/include/linux-x86_64
    gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-mavx2'
    gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-mfma'
    gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-mfpmath=sse'
    gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-march=core-avx2'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-f2b27qwm/blis/setup.py", line 277, in <module>
        "Topic :: Scientific/Engineering",
      File "/home/{user_name}/.conda/envs/ncn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 145, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "/home/{user_name}/.conda/envs/ncn/lib/python3.7/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/home/{user_name}/.conda/envs/ncn/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/home/{user_name}/.conda/envs/ncn/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/home/{user_name}/.conda/envs/ncn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 192, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "/home/{user_name}/.conda/envs/ncn/lib/python3.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/home/{user_name}/.conda/envs/ncn/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/home/{user_name}/.conda/envs/ncn/lib/python3.7/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "/home/{user_name}/.conda/envs/ncn/lib/python3.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/home/{user_name}/.conda/envs/ncn/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/home/{user_name}/.conda/envs/ncn/lib/python3.7/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 340, in run
        self.build_extensions()
      File "/tmp/pip-install-f2b27qwm/blis/setup.py", line 103, in build_extensions
        objects = self.compile_objects(compiler.split("-")[0], arch, OBJ_DIR)
      File "/tmp/pip-install-f2b27qwm/blis/setup.py", line 188, in compile_objects
        objects.append(self.build_object(env=env, **spec))
      File "/tmp/pip-install-f2b27qwm/blis/setup.py", line 201, in build_object
        subprocess.check_call(command, cwd=BLIS_DIR)
      File "/home/{user_name}/.conda/envs/ncn/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 347, in check_call
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['gcc', '-c', '/tmp/pip-install-f2b27qwm/blis/blis/_src/kernels/zen/1/bli_amaxv_zen_int.c', '-o', '/tmp/tmpu1wg8fg1/bli_amaxv_zen_int.o', '-O3', '-mavx2', '-mfma', '-mfpmath=sse', '-march=core-avx2', '-fPIC', '-std=c99', '-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L', '-DBLIS_VERSION_STRING="0.5.1"', '-DBLIS_IS_BUILDING_LIBRARY', '-Iinclude/linux-x86_64', '-I./frame/3/', '-I./frame/ind/ukernels/', '-I./frame/1m/', '-I./frame/1f/', '-I./frame/1/', '-I./frame/include', '-I/tmp/pip-install-f2b27qwm/blis/blis/_src/include/linux-x86_64']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
    ----------------------------------------
    ERROR: Failed building wheel for blis
    Running setup.py clean for blis 
  Failed to build numpy blis
  ERROR: Could not build wheels for numpy which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /home/{user_name}/.conda/envs/ncn/bin/python /home/{user_name}/.conda/envs/ncn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-3j47_tuc/normal --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'cython>=0.25' 'thinc<7.4.0,>=7.3.0' 'preshed<3.1.0,>=3.0.2' 'murmurhash<1.1.0,>=0.28.0' wheel 'cymem<2.1.0,>=2.0.2' Check the logs for full command output.
```

it seems there are numpy problem

but i already installed numpy(1.16.5) while installing pytorch(1.12.0)

some stackoverflow solutions did not solve the problem
([Python Cannot install module spaCy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50483235/python-cannot-install-module-spacy))
([Failed building wheel for spacy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43370851/failed-building-wheel-for-spacy))

because my machine runs on ppc64le, IBM watson machine.
so there are no wheel for my machine.
several packages are available (https://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/server/ibm-ai/conda/#/)
but spaCy is not one of them.

What should I do for installing spaCy?

Comment: Why are you using `pip` instead of `conda`?

Comment: @FlyingTeller I tried 'conda' but it only has spacy 2.0.16 version though my sistem require 2.1.6 version

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, but on Raspberry Pi 4. could some one help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may install version 2.2.1 of spacy compiled for ppc64le in the powerai supplementary channel that was recently added.

`conda install -c powerai spacy`

You may also `git clone https://github.com/IBM/powerai` and modify https://github.com/IBM/powerai/blob/master/conda-recipes/spacy-feedstock/recipe/meta.yaml#L2-L3 to be version 2.1.6 and then conda-build the package yourself if you want that specific version. (You would then run conda-build from the `conda-recipes/spacy-feedstock` directory to generate the conda package)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the package is trying to build code using x86 specific flags: `-mavx`, flags that use SSE, etc. You should contact the package authors about this: they will need to change their package to not use those flags on platforms other than x86.

Comment: Maybe, but I don't know what it would be. You'd could look at the code: looking at what changed between 2.0.16 and the current version would be a good first step. Otherwise you'd need to ask the authors, or maybe someone else will know.