# Receiving an Error while installing web3.py

Tags: python, web3py

I am trying to install `web3.py` through the command `pip install web3` however I cannot succeed without getting an error.

I have tried the advice on [this website](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/troubleshooting.html#setup-environment) however that did not work, below is the error that I receive:

- [Error](https://pastebin.com/raw/N0gUjrGv)
- [Full Console Log](https://pastebin.com/raw/nZYHDrDF)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As advised [here in a related stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43370851/failed-building-wheel-for-spacy), grab various wheel files that are required from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#cytoolz).

In this case it seems you are failing at cytoolz so you can manually install the whl files.

Let's say you are running a 64 bit environment, you can download cytoolz‑0.10.1‑cp38‑cp38‑win_amd64.whl file and run `pip install cytoolz‑0.10.1‑cp38‑cp38‑win_amd64.whl` in the same directory as your whl file

Comment: Are you running the above command using the correct wheel filename/filepath that you downloaded from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#cytoolz)? You can download the whl file based on your environment

Answer (score 0):

Since this is probably windows platform you are using, you need to install [Microsoft C++ build tools](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/) and then also add them to your path, if it still doesn't work I suggest switching to Linux or using WSL

Answer (score 0):

You may need to install those packages

```
sudo apt install python3-dev
sudo apt-get install libevent-dev
sudo apt update
```

[Related answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43370851/failed-building-wheel-for-spacy/68610041#68610041)