# Install SCIP for Python on Windows does not work anymore

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, anaconda, scip

I had a working SCIP installation on Python using the following thread:
[SCIP Python Installation Issue Windows with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44183891/scip-python-installation-issue-windows-with-pip)

Now I have a new laptop and tried to re-install SCIP again but it does not work (I tried on several machines with the identical result). The software versions have changed so I refer to the new versions below.

---

Installation (Environment):

- OS: Windows 10
- Anaconda Version 5.0.1| Release Date: October 25, 2017; Python 3.6 (64 bit)
- PyCharm, 2017.3 (Community Edition)
- Library PySCIPOpt (pip install pyscipopt)
- Unpacked the files from SCIPOPTDIR.rar in directory C:\SCIPOPT
- Set the environment variables:

  - Added the Variable SCIPOPTDIR with the Value of the installation directory (i.e. C:\SCIPOPT)
  - Added in the PATH Variable the entry %SCIPOPTDIR%\lib

---

Error Message:

File "C:/Users/i070009/PycharmProjects/OptimizationModels/RunTestOfSCIPLibrary.py", line 1, in

from pyscipopt import Model, quicksum

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyscipopt'

---

If I use a jupyter Notebook (from pyscipopt import Model, quicksum)  I get the following error message:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 from pyscipopt import Model, quicksum

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyscipopt__init__.py in ()
      1 # export user-relevant objects:

```
  2 from pyscipopt.Multidict import multidict
```

----> 3 from pyscipopt.scip      import Model

```
  4 from pyscipopt.scip      import Branchrule

  5 from pyscipopt.scip      import Conshdlr
```

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

My guess is that the module is not found but since I added the PATH variables (and it worked on my old laptop) I’m puzzled why it does not work.
It might be a really simple problem. I’m just not seeing it! Thanks for any help on this topic!

Comment: Did the command `pip install pyscipopt` even work correctly? I suppose not, if you ran it *before* setting up the SCIP Opt Suite installation.

Comment: Hi Mattmilten
Thanks for your answer. Yes, the installation went without any error messages. Actually it worked in this order on the old computer as well. This is why I did not change anything. Would you recommend to first unpick the SCIPOPT and set the env variables before I use "pip install pyscipopt"?

Answer (score 2):

This is already handled here: https://github.com/SCIP-Interfaces/PySCIPOpt/issues/110

One needs to make sure that the `bin` directory is available in the `PATH` on Windows so both the binary as well as the dll/lib are found during installation and execution of PySCIPOpt.