# Difference in array allocation in function call (gcc and cl.exe)

Tags: c, arrays, gcc, cl

When I use a GCC compiler, i could dynamically allocate the array size in a function using the function input arguments, but the same fails when I compile it using Windows cl.exe compiler. Why.?

```
void func1(int array_ele)
{
    int arr[array_ele];
    for (int i=0; i<array_ele; i++)
        arr[i] = i;
    /* Rest of the code */
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int a = 10;
    func1(a);
    /* Rest of the code */
}
```

Comment: @arrowd: no, it's because VS doesn't implement C99 (VLAs).

Comment: I'd go as far as saying that VS does not have a C compiler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Variable-length arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) was introduced in the C99 standard, and the Microsoft C compiler haven't supported C99 until recently, and its support is still incomplete even in the latest 2015 edition (for example it still doesn't support VLAs).

GCC before version 5 by default used "gnu90" as C-dialect to use, which is an updated version of the C89 standard with GCC extensions, and one of those extensions is VLAs. From version 5 and later the default is "gnu11" which is the latest C11 standard with GCC extensions.

Answer (score 4):

`int arr[array_ele];` is a variable-length array declaration. It is standard C (since C99). However, `cl.exe` is not a standard-compliant C compiler, and Microsoft has basically stated that they do not intend to produce a standard-compliant C compiler (one could assume malicious intent and say they do not want to help writing portable code), focusing instead on implementing C++ features. More discussion about Visual Studio support for C standards at [Visual Studio support for new C / C++ standards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146381/visual-studio-support-for-new-c-c-standards)

Some features of the (by now and then obsoleted) C99 are supported on VS2015 (including library support, and variable declarations anywhere within a block etc); and some standard library functions are implemented: [C++11/14/17 Features In VS 2015 RTM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh409293.aspx) says that:

> Visual Studio 2015 fully implements the C99 Standard Library, *with the exception of any library features that depend on compiler features not yet supported by the Visual C++ compiler (for example, `<tgmath.h>` is not implemented).*

However as far as I know, much of the C99 - let alone C11 - compiler features remain unimplemented.

Comment: You have noted that *implements the C99 standard library* and *support of the C99 standard* means something different? I guess so.

Comment: @tofro Yeah I italicized part of the quote, however I couldn't even find anything definitive about *what* C99 compiler features are actually supported by VS2015.

Answer (score 2):

```
int arr[array_ele];
```

is supported in C99 and later. This is called a variable length array. `gcc` supports it. Microsoft Visual Studio compilers don't seem to support it. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zb1574zs.aspx.